# Dataframe error when clustering groups

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am a little new to clustering in python. I am trying to cluster some data. I am trying to group people on their worknumber. There are several agents who share similar worknums and I am trying to group them together using k means.

Here is what my data looks like

```
        date    agentid     workgroup   direction   worknum
 0  2015-09-01  Adam            Claims   Inbound      1
 1  2015-09-01  Nathaniel       Claims   Inbound      1
 2  2015-09-01  Accorvia        -        Outbound     13
 3  2015-09-01  Jane-   -       Claims   Inbound      1
 4  2015-09-01  Jessica         Benefits Inbound      6
```

Here are the data types:

```
 y.types
date          object
agentid       object
workgroup     object
direction     object
worknum      float64
dtype: object
```

Here is my code for cluster analysis

```
##### cluster data into K=1..10 clusters #####
#K, KM, centroids,D_k,cIdx,dist,avgWithinSS = kmeans.run_kmeans(X,10)

K = range(1,10)

 # scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans
KM = [kmeans(y,k) for k in K] # apply kmeans 1 to 10
centroids = [cent for (cent,var) in KM]   # cluster centroids

D_k = [cdist(y, cent, 'euclidean') for cent in centroids]

cIdx = [np.argmin(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
dist = [np.min(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
avgWithinSS = [sum(d)/y.shape[0] for d in dist]
```

This is throwing me an error:

```
  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I assume this is coming from how I am calling that data but I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Your data doesn't look appropriate for clustering! Do you want [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)? Maybe something like `y.groupby(by='worknum')`

Comment: @atomh33ls maybe I need to change the data around better. I don't want to just group the skill number together. I want to ideally find what people should be in similar groups based on shared work numbers. Or maybe I am just misunderstanding your comment!

Answer (score 0):

### k-means only works on numerical (continuous) attributes

Using it with "string" or "integer" or "date" attributes does not make *sense*.

The *concept* of k-means is that of **least squares**. It literally tries to minimize `(x-mean)^2`. But that equation only exists on *numerical* values, and minimizing squares only makes sense if they are *continuous* (*not* if they are binary, then it reduces to counting).

In other words **k-means cannot be used for your data set**.